# EF Core derived DbContext doesn't list DbSet

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql, entity-framework-core

I have an EF Core 5 project with a DbContext derived class, "TimeCardsContext." That context has a DbSet property. When I go to use the context in a WorkerService class, that property doesn't appear.

[image: Snapshot of error]

The tip when I hover over  Workers is that the symbol cannot be resolved. I don't understand this because DbSet Workers is right there in the context class. In addition, much googling shows language like "dbContext.Workers."

Am I doing something wrong, or is this a "feature"?

Thanks.

Comment: Please post the part of `TimeCardsContext` where you define Workers and also the part that shows dbc is `TimeCardsContext`.

Comment: Turns out I'm a dummy! TC Context describes the time card entity as TImeCards instead of TimeCard. It's always my bad. 

Thank you for looking at this.